# DefinePlugin with Ionic, Angular ,Webpack and Typescript not working

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, webpack, ionic3

I need to inject my process.env variable with the DefinePlugin in the webpack Bundle, I've got the following code in webpack config :

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': JSON.stringify(process.env)
    }),
    ionicWebpackFactory.getIonicEnvironmentPlugin(),
    ionicWebpackFactory.getCommonChunksPlugin()
],
```

In my package.json, i've got that configuration :

```
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.6",
    "@types/node": "^9.6.6",
    ...
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    ....
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "ts-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^6.0.0",
    "tslint": "^5.9.1",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "^5.1.0",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2",
    "webpack": "^4.6.0"
 },
 "config": {
    "ionic_webpack": "./config/webpack.config.js"
 },
```

I've got a service that uses the process.env injected by the plugin :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

declare var process: {
   env: any
};

@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationService {
```

But when i compile even with yarn or npm, i've got this following error:

```
 [10:28:04]  ionic-app-script task: "build"
 [10:28:04]  TypeError: Cannot read property 'compilation' of undefined
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'compilation' of undefined
      at DefinePlugin.apply ...\node_modules\webpack\lib
 \DefinePlugin.js:42:18)
 at Compiler.apply ( ...\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:375:16)
```

And i could not found any similar issue in Google.
Thank you for your help.

Julien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I met same error here. The thing I've done to fix those is: Make sure all loaders were added in `devDependencies`, and upgrade those loaders latest version.

Please check again.

Comment: All the loaders are in the devDependencies in my package.json, maybe it's a loader version problem.

But I've changed all the achitecture to use paths resolving like in this [tutorial](https://github.com/gshigeto/ionic-environment-variables/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: That's great to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

try doing this

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
})
```

Comment: I've tried something like this :
        `new webpack.DefinePlugin({
              'process.env.BACKEND_URL': JSON.stringify(process.env.BACKEND_URL),
              'process.env.DEBUG': JSON.stringify(process.env.DEBUG),
       }),`
But still the same error